# Nonrepetitive representation of a group of lists (with sharing members)

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, sorting

**Background:**
Lets first construct a square graph (the ***ha*** and second ***points*** define to implement periodic boundary condition):

```
points = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 9}, {j, 0, 9}], 1];
list = 10 SortBy[Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, -1, 1}, {j, -1, 1}], 1], 
    Total[Abs@#] &];
points = Flatten[
   Table[(points\[Transpose] + x)\[Transpose], {x, list}], 1];
ha = Flatten[
   SortBy[GatherBy[
      AdjacencyMatrix[NearestNeighborGraph[points]][
       "NonzeroPositions"], First], #[[1, 1]] &][[1 ;; 
      Length@points/9]], 1];
gr = Graph[
   Select[DeleteDuplicates[
     Flatten[{#, 
         Reverse@#} & /@ ({ha[[All, 1]], 
          Mod[ha[[All, 2]] - 1, Length@points/9] + 1}\[Transpose]), 
      1]], #[[1]] > #[[2]] &]];
```

where gives,

[image]

now I want to assign each vortex, a neighboring face.
I can do it by using the following trick

```
fc = FindCycle[mySquareGraph, {4}, All];
```

where some of them listed below

```
fc[[1 ;; 3]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

and first face highlight as bellow

[image]

now I can list the points which make the faces coordinates,

```
FACE=fc[[All, All, 1]];
FACE[[1;;10]]//MatrixForm
```

[image]

Now assigning a vertex to a face becomes finding a nonrepetitive representation from this list.
I try the following algorithm,

```
    M = Table[0, {i, 1, Length@fc}];
M[[1]] = FACE[[1,1]];
Do[M[[i]] = 
   DeleteCases[RandomSample@FACE[[i]], 
     Alternatives @@ M[[1 ;; i - 1]]][[1]];, {i, 2, Length@fc}]
```

I hoped M containers vortex position belonging to i'th face. However, this algorithm is failed.
Consider I want to generalized to another graph. So let clear my question:

**Question**
Consider following list,

```
{{1, 2, 12, 11}, {2, 12, 13, 3}, {3, 13, 14, 4}, {4, 14, 15, 5}, {6, 
  16, 15, 5}, {7, 8, 18, 17}, {7, 17, 16, 6}, {9, 10, 20, 19}, {9, 19,
   18, 8}, {11, 21, 22, 12}, {12, 13, 23, 22}, {13, 23, 24, 14}, {15, 
  16, 26, 25}, {15, 25, 24, 14}, {16, 17, 27, 26}, {27, 17, 18, 
  28}, {27, 26, 36, 37}, {27, 37, 38, 28}, {28, 18, 19, 29}, {28, 38, 
  39, 29}, {30, 20, 19, 29}, {30, 29, 39, 40}, {32, 31, 21, 22}, {33, 
  23, 22, 32}, {33, 43, 42, 32}, {34, 24, 23, 33}, {35, 25, 24, 
  34}, {35, 36, 26, 25}, {35, 45, 44, 34}, {35, 45, 46, 36}, {37, 38, 
  48, 47}, {37, 47, 46, 36}, {39, 40, 50, 49}, {39, 49, 48, 38}, {41, 
  31, 32, 42}, {41, 51, 52, 42}, {43, 44, 54, 53}, {43, 53, 52, 
  42}, {44, 43, 33, 34}, {45, 55, 54, 44}, {45, 55, 56, 46}, {47, 57, 
  58, 48}, {48, 49, 59, 58}, {49, 59, 60, 50}, {52, 51, 61, 62}, {52, 
  53, 63, 62}, {53, 63, 64, 54}, {55, 65, 66, 56}, {57, 47, 46, 
  56}, {57, 67, 66, 56}, {58, 59, 69, 68}, {58, 68, 67, 57}, {60, 59, 
  69, 70}, {61, 71, 72, 62}, {63, 62, 72, 73}, {63, 64, 74, 73}, {65, 
  55, 54, 64}, {65, 75, 74, 64}, {66, 67, 77, 76}, {68, 78, 77, 
  67}, {69, 79, 78, 68}, {73, 74, 84, 83}, {75, 65, 66, 76}, {75, 76, 
  86, 85}, {75, 85, 84, 74}, {80, 70, 69, 79}, {80, 90, 89, 79}, {81, 
  82, 72, 71}, {81, 91, 92, 82}, {82, 83, 73, 72}, {82, 92, 93, 
  83}, {83, 84, 94, 93}, {84, 94, 95, 85}, {85, 95, 96, 86}, {86, 87, 
  77, 76}, {87, 86, 96, 97}, {88, 78, 77, 87}, {88, 89, 79, 78}, {88, 
  98, 97, 87}, {89, 99, 100, 90}, {98, 88, 89, 99}}
```

Is there any general algorithm, find a group of a nonrepetitive representative from these lists. In other words, can we choose a member from each list, which not being identical?

Comment: Sorry, what is a _plaque_ ? That's not a graph theory term I'm familiar with.

Comment: I'm fairly sure your problem at the end of the question is one a difficult NP-Complete ones. You either frame it as a SAT problem and pass to `FindInstance` or do a brute force search with backtracking. It's like a tour on the graph `SimpleGraph[
 DeleteCases[
  Flatten[Outer[DirectedEdge, #[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ 
    Partition[elements, 2, 1]], DirectedEdge[x_, x_]]]` but unfortunately `FindShortestTour` is not implemented for directed graphs :(

Comment: ^ you could use the resource function [`BacktrackSearch`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BacktrackSearch) like this: `BacktrackSearch = ResourceFunction["BacktrackSearch"]; result = BacktrackSearch[elements, DuplicateFreeQ, Sort[#] == Range[100] &]` however this will take a very long time to find a solution.

Comment: @flinty, sorry for any inconvenience. I change the plaque to face. I am thinking about your comment. I just need to calculate it ones in my calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `faces` defined as the list of 4-tuples in OP, we can construct a bipartite graph from `faces` to `Union @@ faces` using [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) and  use [`FindIndependentEdgeSet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIndependentEdgeSet.html) to find a matching:

```
vlist = Union @@ faces;
rg = RelationGraph[MemberQ, faces, vlist, ImageSize -> 900, 
  VertexSize -> Tiny, ImagePadding -> {{100, 50}, {5, 5}}, 
  VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed["Name", If[Head[v] === List, Before, After]]}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

We can construct the edge list directly from `faces` without using `RelationGraph`:

```
edgelist = Flatten[Thread[DirectedEdge[#, #], List, {2}] & /@ faces];
```

After sorting `edgelist` is the same as `EdgeList[rg]`:

```
Sort[edgelist] == EdgeList[rg]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

```
g2 = Graph[edgelist, ImageSize -> 900, VertexSize -> Tiny, 
 ImagePadding -> {{100, 50}, {5, 5}}, 
 VertexLabels -> {v_ :> 
    Placed["Name", If[Head[v] === List, Before, After]]}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"]
```

> same picture

To get a system of distinct representatives for `faces`, we can use `FindIndependentEdgeSet` with `rg` or `g2`:

```
distinctrepresentatives = FindIndependentEdgeSet[rg]
```

[image]

```
SetProperty[rg, EdgeStyle -> {e_ -> Opacity[0], 
    Alternatives @@ distinctrepresentatives -> Red}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can use `` SparseArray`MaximalBipartiteMatching `` on `AdjacencyMatrix` of `rg`:

```
distinctrepresentatives2 =  SparseArray`MaximalBipartiteMatching[AdjacencyMatrix @ rg] /.
  {i_, j_} :>  DirectedEdge[faces[[i]], j - Length @ faces]
```

[image]

```
SetProperty[rg, 
 EdgeStyle -> {e_ -> Opacity[0], Alternatives @@ distinctrepresentatives2 -> Green}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Yes. This gives the answer. However, it is somehow slow. I changed the code to followings:

Comment: rg = Flatten[
   ParallelTable[
    Table[faces[[i]] \[DirectedEdge] faces[[i, j]], {j, 1, 
      Length@faces[[i]]}], {i, 1, Length@faces}], 1];

Comment: @Rasoul-Ghadimi, please check if the alternative approach (constructing an edge list from `faces` directly without using `RelationGraph`) is any faster.

Comment: because RelationGraph checks any element of both face and vertex group is slow. However, we know where the links are. I bring code in my previous comment.  using RelationGraph takes a long time for 10000 points (unfinished task), but using face just takes about 0.3 seconds. Anyway, thank you for your post and answer.