# Choosing elements from a list of lists so that no elements are same

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to construct a list having one element from each of the lists inside `list1` below such that no element is chosen more than once.

```
list1 = {
  {f[a]}, 
  {f[b]}, 
  {f[b], f[c]}, 
  {f[b], f[c], f[d], f[e], f[g], f[h]}
};
```

The goal is to obtain:

```
ans = {f[a], f[b], f[c], f[d]};
```

The length of `ans` should be the same as the length of `list1`.

How I can obtain it in Mathematica?

Comment: Is the size of your example representative, or do you want to handle larger lists?

Comment: I want to handle a larger list. The size of the list in this example is not representative.

Answer (score 7):

Construct a list of edges from the input list and use `` SparseArray`MaximalBipartiteMatching `` or [`FindIndependentEdgeSet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIndependentEdgeSet.html) to
get a matching:

```
edgelist = Flatten[Thread[DirectedEdge[#, #], List, {2}] & /@ list1];
```

**1. `` SparseArray`MaximalBipartiteMatching ``**

```
matching = SparseArray`MaximalBipartiteMatching[AdjacencyMatrix @ edgelist] /. 
  {i_, j_} :> Rule @@ VertexList[edgelist][[{i, j}]]
```

[image: > {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}]

```
Values @ matching
```

> ```
> {f[a], f[b], f[c], f[d]}
> ```

Alternatively, define a function to get the result in a single step:

```
ClearAll[distinctReps1]
distinctReps1 = Module[{el = Flatten[Thread[DirectedEdge[#, #], List, {2}] & /@ #]},
  # /. Extract[VertexList[el], 
        List /@ SparseArray`MaximalBipartiteMatching[AdjacencyMatrix@el], 
        Apply[Rule]]] &;

distinctReps1[list1]
```

> ```
> {f[a], f[b], f[c], f[d]}
> ```

**2. `FindIndependentEdgeSet`**

```
distinctreps = FindIndependentEdgeSet @ edgelist
```

[image]

```
Map[Last] @ distinctreps
```

> ```
> {f[a], f[b], f[c], f[g]}
> ```

```
ClearAll[distinctReps2]
distinctReps2 = Module[{el = Flatten[Thread[DirectedEdge[#, #], List, {2}] & /@ #]},
     # /. Rule @@@ FindIndependentEdgeSet@el] &;

distinctReps2[list1]
```

> ```
> {f[a], f[b], f[c], f[g]}
> ```

```
graph = Graph[edgelist,
   ImagePadding -> {{100, 50}, {5, 5}}, 
   VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed["Name", If[Head[v] === List, Before, After]]}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"];

HighlightGraph[graph, 
 Style[distinctreps, Directive[Opacity[.5], Red, AbsoluteThickness[5]]]]
```

[image]

**Related Q/A:** [Nonrepetitive representation of a group of lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/229108/125)

Answer (score 7):

For larger lists, I think you can use [`LinearProgramming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming). Here's a function that does this.

```
pick[l:{__List}] := Module[{elems, lens, lefts, unique, m},
    elems = Flatten @ l;
    lens = Length /@ l;
    lefts = Accumulate[Prepend[0] @ Most @ lens];
    unique = DeleteDuplicates @ elems;
    m = Join[
        MapThread[
            PadRight[ConstantArray[1, #1], Length[elems], 0, #2]&,
            {lens, lefts}
        ],
        Transpose[
            UnitVector[Length[unique], #]& /@ ArrayComponents[elems]
        ]
    ];
    lp = Quiet[
        LinearProgramming[
            ConstantArray[-1, Length[elems]],
            m,
            Table[{1, -1}, Length[m]],
            0,
            Integers
        ],
        LinearProgramming::lpip
    ];
    Pick[elems, lp, 1]
]
```

Your example:

```
pick[list]
```

> {f[a], f[b], f[c], f[h]}

I don't have time to explain how it works at the moment, but I will add some explanatory text later.

Answer (score 5):

> The goal is to obtain ans = {f[a], f[b], f[c], f[d]};

I wrote this solution using somewhat Fortran style. I hope that is OK.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
list1 = {{f[a]}, {f[b]}, {f[b], f[c]}, {f[b], f[c], f[d], f[e], f[g],f[h]}}
collection = {};
Do[Do[If[Not[MemberQ[collection, n]], AppendTo[collection, n]; 
    Break[]], {n, m}], {m, list1}
  ];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you prefer a more true Mathematica functional solution using `@@/% ## :*&` type notations then I am sure someone will post such solution soon. I could not find one quickly myself. When all else fails, there is a good old fashioned Loop!

Answer (score 4):

There is more than one result that match the criteria.

```
list1 = {{f[a]}, {f[b]}, {f[b], f[c]}, 
  {f[b], f[c], f[d], f[e], f[g], f[h]}};

Select[Tuples[list1], Length[Union[#]] == Length[list1] &]

(* {{f[a], f[b], f[c], f[d]}, {f[a], f[b], f[c], f[e]}, 
  {f[a], f[b], f[c], f[g]}, {f[a], f[b], f[c], f[h]}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing it. Yes, indeed there can be more results matching the criteria. I just need any one of them.

Comment: `DuplicateFreeQ` feels ignored ;)

Comment: @BenIzd - Yes, `DuplicateFreeQ` is about twice as fast using `RepeatedTiming`

Answer (score 4):

```
list1 = {{f[a]}, {f[b]}, {f[b], f[c]}, {f[b], f[c], f[d], f[e], f[g], f[h]}};
helper[acc_, lst_] := Append[acc, RandomChoice@Complement[lst, acc]]
Fold[helper, {}, list1]
```

Answer (score 3):

We may try to solve this by accumulating the result in a variable: res. We start with an empty res. We first look at the first sub-list and determine the first element that is not in res (it will be the first element). We then add this element to res. Then we inspect the next sub-list and do the same.

Here is the code for this:

```
list1 = {{f[a]}, {f[b]}, {f[b], f[c]}, {f[b], f[c], f[d], f[e], f[g], 
    f[h]}};
res = {};
AppendTo[res, (Select[#, Function[x, ! MemberQ[res, x]]][[1]])] & /@ 
  list1;
res

{f[a], f[b], f[c], f[d]}
```